# Error NoReverseMatch on Reverse Django URL

Tags: django

I have declared an url like following in django 1.7:

> url(r'^page(/\w{2}/|/)$', MyView.as_view(), name='my_name'),

In my template, I want to reverse the url from its name. I tried:

```
<form  method="post" action="{% url 'my_namespace:my_name' variable %}">

<form  method="post" action="{% url 'my_namespace:my_name' %}">
```

But nothing works, it throwed exception:

Reverse for 'my_name' with arguments '(u'test',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['page(\/\w{2}\/|\/)$']

Please help by giving me some advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex appears incorrect for matching the argument 'test'.

If we take a look at the regex `(/\w{2}/|/)`,
It appears to be capturing two groups which are separated by an 'OR' (|) operator.

The first group is `/\w{2}/`.  This is only going to match '/' followed by \w only 2 times followed by '/'.

The second group is only matching '/'.

'test' doesn't match either one of these cases so it raises an exception.

I believe the correct regex we are looking to capture here would be,

```
(\w+)
```

The correct URL structure would look like this,

```
url(r'^page/(\w+)/$', MyView.as_view(), name='my_name')
url(r'^page/$', MyView.as_view(), name='my_name')
```

This would match given the argument 'test' because the regex `(\w+)` says match any of the characters in this group `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` one or more times and each character in 'test' falls into this category.

Comment: I tried passing a two characters variables 'ab' instead of 'test' but it still not work. However, if I split that url into 2 like your suggestion, it works well. Is this possible two use only one url declaration?

Comment: Yeah, the arguments in the URL will disambiguate the call to the URL.